# Cannot find symbol- method getNext()?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am running BlueJ as my IDE. For some odd reason I get an error in this line of code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class RotateArrayCircularLL
{
    private Node head=null;   

    // ==================================================================================
    public void init()
    {

       int choice = 0;

        while (choice != -1){
        choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter -1 to stop loop, 1 to continue"));    

        if(choice == -1)
            break;

        inputNum();

      }
      printList();
    }

    public void inputNum()   
    {
        Node n;
        Node temp;
        int k;

        k = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a number:"));
        n = new Node(k);       

         if (head == null) {
            head = n;            
         } else {            
            temp = head;
            while (temp.getNext() != null)
                temp = temp.getNext();

            temp.setNext(n);                
        }       

    } 


    public void printList()  
    {
        Node temp = head;
        Node d, e;

        int count =  Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the value to shift to the right"));

        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) // Rotates the head
            temp = temp.getNext();

        for (e = head; e != null; e = e.getNext()){
           if (e.getNext() != null)
            System.out.print(e.getInfo() + "-");
           if (e.getNext() == null)
            System.out.print(e.getInfo()); 
        }

        for (Node c = temp; c != null && c.getNext() != head; c= c.getNext()){ 
                System.out.print(c.getInfo() + "-");
        }
        for (d = head; d != null && d.getNext() != temp; d = d.getNext())
        {
            System.out.print(d.getInfo()+ "-");
        }
        System.out.println(d.getInfo());
    } 


}
```

The error is: Cannot find symbol- method getNext().

The code was working perfectly before but recently my compiler froze and was not responding so I ended the process via Task Manager. Since then it started to act up.

Can anyone explain why it is not working? I don't think that it is my issue, but rather the compilers.

Comment: A little more context would help - what object type is `temp`?  What are its methods and [consequently] their signatures?

Comment: What is the type (class) of `temp`?  Is it one of your own classes, or some system class? Are you sure it has a `getNext()` method?

Comment: what is temp? Please post more code which comes before the while loop.

Comment: temp is just a Node, But that is not what is causing the error. The actual method itself is

Comment: @user1136610, that is absolutely what is causing the error. The compiler isn't finding a `getNext()` method on `temp`, and so whatever `temp` is, is where the problem lies.

Comment: Okay, can you post the class code then?

Comment: Have you changed the build path (classpath) lately? Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project? And in what class has getNext() been defined, what's the type of temp? Finally, why are you calling getNext() twice in the same loop, aren't you skipping an element this way?

Comment: I have not done so recently. And I'm not sure how to clean the project

Comment: The code provided is the code *invoking* the Node object.  What is required is the code *specifically for* the Node class.

Answer (score 0):

The likely cases are either:

- The method `getNext()` does not exist within the Node class, or
- the calling signature of `getNext()` doesn't match with how it's defined (despite it being an accessor).

I can't say for certain which line of code is causing it, as you haven't provided code for the Node class.  However, comb through the Node class and make certain that both `getNext()` exists, and you're calling it the way you're supposed to (passing valid arguments, and so forth).

Answer (score 0):

Check the xml files. I had the same problem. I was calling a TextView that I previously rename and forgot to change the name.